# Why is the Apache2 module not in the mods-available library?

Tags: apache2, 20.04, php

I installed both PHP 5.6 and 7.4 and their apache2 modules:

```
$ sudo apt install php5.6 libapache2-mod-php5.6
$ sudo apt install php7.4 libapache2-mod-php7.4
```

However, when I try to enable php7.4, I get an error:

```
$ sudo a2enmod php7.4
ERROR: Module php7.4 does not exist!
```

Indeed, the module is not found where it should be:

```
$ ls -la /etc/apache2/mods-available/php*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 867 May 14 11:48 /etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.6.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 102 May 14 11:48 /etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.6.load
```

php5.6 is there, but php7.4 is not. How can I fix this?

Comment: Hello, I think you need to provide some additional information. Which version of Ubuntu is in use? Does there some additional ppa like as `ppa:ondrej/php`?

Comment: It's 20.04, and yes, I installed PHP from ondrej

Answer (score 0):

Are you try `a2enmod php7.0` ? Probably it's the correct version to use under Php7.4

Comment: I get a similar error "Module php7.0 does not exist!" and similarly with "a2enmod php7". Indeed both these modules are not in the mods-available folder.